# How to completely remove audio (kmix, pulseaudio) on kubuntu-desktop for rdp/x2go

Tags: sound, kubuntu, pulseaudio, remote-desktop, kmix

I use a ubuntu-server distribution (14.04) along with the package "kubuntu-desktop" to allow users to log in remotely and access a desktop. I currently use "x2go" as the remote-desktop connection software, but this question applies more to the desktop packages rather than the connection client. The server is also hosted using AWS, if that is relevant.

I now have about 10 regular users on the system. A concern that has come to my attention is the usage of audio processes on the server. I can run top and see many "kmix" processes, which take about 5% cpu each, and many "pulseaudio" processes, which range from 2-10% cpu each. In the case of "kmix", it looks like the same user is even spawning more than one process.

This is a serious drain on system resources, and there is no use of sound whatsoever in the usage of this system. (it is a research platform) How can I cleanly remove or disable all audio processes and features, system wide, from the "kubuntu-desktop" package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable sound in the session settings on the client. If this does not help, try disabling autostart of pulseaudio for the users.
Removing pulseaudio completely from the system may result in unpredictable behaviour.

Edit: Setting "autospawn = no" in /etc/pulse/client.conf should keep pulseaudio from autostarting for all users (`man pulse-client.conf`). For further explanation, see e.g. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Configuration